# Heroku Hobby Plan total dyno hours

Tags: node.js, express, heroku, server, hoisting

In heroku hobby plan, there are 7$/dyno/month.

I know that in free plan there is 550 free dynos(without credit card) per month.

**But I can't find out how many dyno hours I can enjoy in heroku hobby plan???**

***Please tell me here***

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you mentioned hobby plan is not free, so you don't have worry about dyno hours. You pay max $7 for hobby dynos but less if it's stopped/paused.

https://www.heroku.com/pricing

For Hobby it says "Prorated to the second" which means that the minimum time they charge you is a second.